# Update data in db django after reload page with discord auth

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, discord

I make authorize with my discord, when user auth I save data to my database but when user changes his nickname in discord, I dont get `new` version of nickname in database, how to fix this?

```
@login_required(login_url = "/oauth2/login")
def get_authenticated_user(request: HttpRequest):
    user = request.user
    context = {
        "id" : user.id,
        "avatar": user.avatar,
        "public_flags" : user.public_flags,
        "flags" : user.flags,
        "locale" : user.locale,
        "mfa_enabled" : user.mfa_enabled,
        "discord_tag" : user.discord_tag,
    }
    request.session['userid'] = user.id

    print(user.id)
    return render(request,"paypal.html", context=context)
```

with this code I render my user page and also I have this:

```
class DiscordAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, user) -> DiscordUser:
        find_user = DiscordUser.objects.filter(id = user['id'])
        print(find_user)
        print(user)
        if len(find_user) == 0:
            print("User not found, saving")
            new_user = DiscordUser.objects.create_new_discord_user(user)
            print(new_user)
            return new_user
        else:
            print("User found!!!!")
            new_user = DiscordUser.objects.update_or_create(id = user['id'], defaults= {
                'avatar': user['avatar'],
                'discord_tag': f"{user['username']}#{user['discriminator']}"},
                )[0]
            print(new_user)
            return new_user
    
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return DiscordUser.objects.get(pk = user_id)
        except DiscordUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

this code means after login we create new user or update in database, but I want do that when I change discord avatar I want to update my data in database

Comment: It's hard to help without possibility to see the code. Share related parts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: okay, Ill send code rn